# Comparison Test for Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that the series below converges by the comparison test.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n^3+5^n+5\log(n)}{13-n+8^n}
\end{align}

How do I show that:

\begin{align}
\frac{2n^3+5^n+5\log(n)}{13-n+8^n} \le 16\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^n
\end{align}

Comment: You can just use limit comparison test

Comment: Work separately with the numerator and denominator.  Get an upper bound on the numerator as a multiple of $5^n$ and a lower bound on the denominator as a multiple of $8^n$.

Comment: What would I change -n to in order to make it a multiple of 8?

Answer (score 2):

Simple with *asymptotic equivalence* of functions:

- $2n^3+5^n+5\log n\sim_\infty 5^n$,
- $13-n+8^n\sim_\infty 8^n$,
  so that

$$\frac{2n^3+5^n+5\log n}{13-n+8^n}\sim_\infty\frac{5^n}{8^n}=\Bigl(\frac 58\Bigr)^{\!n},\quad\text{a convergent geometric series.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note for n>1:
$$ 
\dfrac{2n^3 + 5^n + 5\log(n)}{13-n+8^n}  \leq \dfrac{2\cdot 5^n + 5^n + 5^n}{\frac{8^n}{2}} =  8\bigg( \frac{5}{8} \bigg)^n 
$$
and note that $\frac{5}{8} < 1$ so the series will converges by geometric series.

Comment: What do you change the -n  to?

Comment: Note that $8^n - n > 8^n/2$ for $n>1$. Then this implies that $\frac{1}{8^n - n} < \frac{1}{\frac{8^n}{2} }$

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question, what was your intuition to use 8/2? I think that is what I am struggling with. i.e If I were to look at the question, what made you approach it this way?

Comment: The goal was to some how express everything in term of exponential functions, $8^n$, and  $5^n$ . This way, we can group them together! But when we do that, we need to also make sure the inequality is going in the right direction. In this case, I want to make the denominator smaller. As for how or why I picked $8^n/2$, that just come to playing around with it a little bit. Plug in some values and see what is going on. Plug in $n=1$, and $n=2$ and you can see that the inequality hold. Also note that $8^n$ is an exponential function so it's increasing for $n>1$.